# How to communicate logstash pipelines

Tags: logstash

I want in one instance there has to be two logstash pipelines running,one of them's output will be the other one's input.
I have read below documentations,

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/ls-to-ls.html
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html#pipeline-to-pipeline-overview
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-lumberjack.html

I'm confused about which approach I should follow.
The thing  I want is below :

The first logstash :

```
input {
 # someplugins and codecs are here
}
filter {
 # some operations here
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
  ... 
 }
 file {
  ...
 }
 logstash {
 }
}
```

Second one like below :

```
input {
   logstash {
   }
}
filter {
   #some operations are here
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
  }
}
```

I know there is no plugin that name is logstash. I put that name for explaining the situations.
So, for this purpose what should i follow ? Should i need message queue (kafka,redis) or lumberjack protocol or should i need beats for this purpose **or is there any better alternative** ?

Can someone answer with basic pipeline for this purpose ?

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below one is the easiest way that the solves question.

```
- pipeline.id: first_pipeline
  config.string: 
    input { stdin { } }
    output { pipeline { send_to => [commonOut] } }
- pipeline.id: second_pipeline
  config.string: |
    input { pipeline { address => commonOut } }
    filter {
    }
    output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }
```